# which is more efficient dict.get("1", "default val") or if else check

Tags: python

I have dict

```
my_dict  = {
        "1": "sss", "2": "dddd", "3": "ssss",
        "4": "ccc", "5": "aaa", "6": "ffff"
        }
```

which is more efficient in terms of time complexity?

`myvar = my_dict.get("7", "default value")`

OR

```
if "7" in  my_dict :
     myvar = my_dict["7"]
else:
    myvar = "default value"
```

aren't they both same because in the implementation of dict.get there there will be if else condition and then return default value ?

Comment: Should be the same....

Comment: Why not test it yourself? :)

Comment: In term, of complexity, it shall be the same (you could make a benchmark to check). It is more about readability of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for speed, `else` method works slightly faster. This slight difference happens since,

1. get is an attribute, so Python has to look this up, and then bind the descriptor found to the dictionary instance.
2. () is a call, so the current frame has to be pushed on the stack, a call has to be made, then the frame has to be popped again from the stack to continue.

```py
import time

print("++++++++++Small Dict++++++++++++")

my_dict  = {
        "1": "sss", "2": "dddd", "3": "ssss",
        "4": "ccc", "5": "aaa", "6": "ffff"
        }

start = time.time()
myvar = my_dict.get("7", "default value")
print("myvar: ", myvar)
print("Time taken for get method: ", time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
if "7" in  my_dict :
     myvar = my_dict["7"]
else:
    myvar = "default value"
print("myvar: ", myvar)
print("Time taken for else method: ", time.time() - start)

print("++++++++++Big Dict++++++++++++")

for i in range(10000):
    my_dict[str(i)] = str(i)

start = time.time()
myvar = my_dict.get("100000000", "default value")
print("myvar: ", myvar)
print("Time taken for get method: ", time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
if "100000000" in  my_dict :
     myvar = my_dict["7"]
else:
    myvar = "default value"
print("myvar: ", myvar)
print("Time taken for else method: ", time.time() - start)
```

Output

```
++++++++++Small Dict++++++++++++
myvar:  default value
Time taken for get method:  8.821487426757812e-06
myvar:  default value
Time taken for else method:  7.152557373046875e-06
++++++++++Big Dict++++++++++++
myvar:  default value
Time taken for get method:  3.62396240234375e-05
myvar:  default value
Time taken for else method:  8.106231689453125e-06
```

Comment: Your timings don't have much meaning, as 1/ Using `time()` on one run of a function gives totally unreliable values. See [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html). 2/ You only ran your tests in the case where the key was missing from the dict.

Comment: 1. I'll update it with `timeit` in that case 2. I think I'm testing the `else` and `.get()` cases, so the measured time should be where the key is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the comparison of the two

```
d = {str(k): k**2 for k in range(10000)}
In[85]: def check(d):
   ...:     if '899' in d:
   ...:         return d['899']
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return "None"
   ...:     

n[86]: %timeit check(d)
102 ns ± 0.875 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In[87]: %timeit d.get('899', 'None')
62.1 ns ± 0.282 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```